# iterating a list of fields with ng-repeat and generate more data to be sent to the controller via ng-click,

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help approaching the problem better or guide me a bit, I'm new angular.

I must first iterate a list of headers of a .csv file that list I have to make a match of three predefined fields, the remaining headers I have to generate a ng-repeat for so for each record generating radiobuttons and inputs with information I serve to create a new object, but when I click on the button that sends through the data ng-click on the controller this undefined

```
//controller
app.controller('fileController', [
'$scope',
'$http',
'ngAuthSettings',
'$location',
'localStorageService',
'fileService', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, ngAuthSettings, $location, localStorageService, fileService, $rootScope) {

    var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;
    var headersMatch = [];
    var _lista_de_Headers = [];
    var _lista_de_tags = [];
    var _lista_de_header_splice = [];
    $scope.restantesTag = [];

    $scope.displayed = false;
    $scope.secondDisplay = false;

    //this is ok, get data from api and the header of file uploaded
    $scope.uploadFile = function () {

        var file = $scope.recipient;

        fileService.uploadFileToUrl(file).then(
            function (results) {

                _lista_de_Headers = results.data.Headers;
                _lista_de_header_splice = angular.copy(results.data.Headers);
                _lista_de_tags = results.data.Tags;

                $scope.displayed = true;
                $scope.listaDeHeaders = _lista_de_Headers;
            },
            function (error) {
                var errors = [];
                for (var key in error.data.modelState) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < error.data.modelState[key].length; i++) {
                        errors.push(error.data.modelState[key][i]);
                    }
                }
                $scope.message = "Falla n:" + errors.join(' ');
            }
        );
    };
    //iterates the received data and creates an object with three main fields match
    $scope.headerPpal = function (item) {
        angular.forEach(item, function (index, element) {
            headersMatch.push({
                'Header': { "numberColumn": index.numberColumn, "nameColumn": element },
                'Match': index.nameColumn,
                'isReplace': false,
                'Rename': null
            });
            angular.forEach(_lista_de_header_splice, function (i, obj) {
                if (i.nameColumn === index.nameColumn) {
                    _lista_de_header_splice.splice(obj, 1);
                };
            });
        });

        $scope.secondDisplay = true;
        $scope.restantesTag = _lista_de_header_splice;
        $scope.listaDeTags = _lista_de_tags;
        $rootScope.headersMatch = headersMatch;
        $rootScope.lista_de_header_splice = _lista_de_header_splice;
    };

    $scope.mivariable = function (item) {
        //Here is undefined the item
    };

}]);
```

in the view

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4 class="page-header">Mantenedor de Archivos</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Subir archivo
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <div class="upl form-group pull-left col-lg-10">
                            <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload btn btn-block btn-info pull-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Seleccione archivo...
                            </label>
                            <input id="file-upload" type="file" file-model="recipient" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group pull-left col-lg-2">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="uploadFile()" value="Subir" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" ng-show="displayed">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Seleccione Campos principales:
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 center-block">
                                <span>
                                    Email
                                    <select ng-model="header.Email" ng-options="item.nameColumn for item in listaDeHeaders">
                                        <!--<option value="null">No aplica</option>-->
                                    </select>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 center-block">
                                <span>
                                    Nombre
                                    <select ng-model="header.Name" ng-options="item as item.nameColumn for item in listaDeHeaders">
                                        <option value="dontHave">No aplica</option>
                                    </select>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 center-block">
                                <span>
                                    Fecha Nacimiento
                                    <select ng-model="header.BirthDate" ng-options="item as item.nameColumn for item in listaDeHeaders">
                                        <option value="dontHave">no aplica</option>
                                    </select>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <button id="step1_next" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="headerPpal(header)">
                                siguiente
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" ng-show="secondDisplay">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Agregue configuracion de Tags:
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">

                            <div ng-repeat="tag in restantesTag">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="tag.nameColumn" class="form-control success" placeholder="{{tag.nameColumn}}" value="{{tag.nameColumn}}" disabled>
                                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="tag.numberColumn" value="{{tag.numberColumn}}" hidden>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" data-ng-model="tag.isReplace" value="true" />Agregar<br />
                                    <input type="radio" data-ng-model="tag.isReplace" value="false" />Reemplazar
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span>
                                        <select data-ng-model="tag.Header" ng-options="x for x in listaDeTags">
                                            <option value="">No aplica</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div><input type="text" data-ng-model="tag.Value" class="form-control"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="mivariable(tag)">
                                    Guardar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for everything !!

Comment: Where are you calling `mivariable`? I don't see anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: last button calling in the ng-click @HanletEscaño

Comment: @oguzhan00 Oh, wow how did I miss that? Thanks!

Comment: at the end of html, the following button

Comment: In that case, you have your button _outside_ your `ng-repeat`. @Cristian Bermedo. That's why you get `undefined`, cause `tag` does not exist there (out of scope).

Comment: <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="mivariable(tag)">
                                    Guardar
                                </button>
                            </div>

Comment: I need to send everything that is selected for all records in the ng-repeat

Comment: I understand, but the button is calling `mivariable` with an undefined value, because it is outside the `ng-repeat`. You need to move your button inside the div with `ng-repeat` (or move `<div class="form-group col-lg-12">`).

Comment: Why do you need to send ``tag`` to the ``mivariable()`` function?  There could be 50 tags but your button is outside of the ng-repeat list.  Without knowing why you need one specific tag item in the function, it's hard to tell you how to fix it.